# How to bypass or configure okta credentials in Jmeter GUI for a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmeter, okta

I am working in a spring boot application its having few rest apis. When we execute those api's in browser we need to authenticate using our OKTA verification process.

when I trired to execute `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/users/10` it gives okta verification error.

I am not sure where to put my username and password of OKTA in jmeter tool to execute my apis

Here is my configuration: **[Version of Jmeter - 2.5.1]**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[OKTA authentication](https://developer.okta.com/books/api-security/authn/api-authentication-options/#authn-api-authentication-options) is basically sending Authorization header with value of Basic 
 and base 64 encoded of user and password.

> Authorization: Basic base64(username:password)

You can follow [OctoPerf](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/24/jmeter-basic-authentication/) with 3 ways to send such authentication in JMeter

For example:

[image]

[image]

Note your version of JMeter is very very old, last version is [5.1.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html)

Comment: I am bound to use this version @Ubik. No luck with this

Comment: @DeskToDevelop did you tried with the 3 ways suggested? if it still doesn't work you can edit your question with your tries